# Send a single API request by waiting for both the fields to be selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using React with Typescript. I have a requirement where we have a filters section with DateRangePicker as one field and dropdown of checkboxes as another. Whenever a date range is selected in the calendar and Ok is clicked we have a handler function that gets called which in turn dispatches a redux action and subsequently api request is sent to filter the data based on the selected date range. Similarly when we check or uncheck a checkbox in the second field another handler function gets called which in turn dispatches a redux action and subsequently api request is sent to filter the data based on the checked data. Now, I need to wait 5 seconds for the user after he/she selects the date range and see if the user checks a checkbox within 5 seconds. If yes, I need to just send a single api request instead of two(one for date range selection and one for checkbox selection). This is how my handler functions look like below

```
const dateChangeHandler = (value: DateRange | null, event: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
    setSelectedDateRange(value);
    dispatch(fetchFilteredData({ payload: { dateRange: value, selectedTools: selectedTools } }))
}

const selectionChangeHandler = (value: string[]) => {
    if (value.length > 0) {
        setSelectedTools(value);
        dispatch(fetchFilteredData({ payload: { dateRange: selectedDateRange, selectedTools: value } }))
    } else {
        dispatch(fetchFilteredData({ payload: { dateRange: selectedDateRange, selectedTools: [] } }))
    }
```

};

Any idea how I can proceed further with this? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timeout that, 5s later will trigger the dispatch event. Store the timeout ID in a state/ref and clearTimeout in the other input handler:

```
const [timeoutId, setTimeoutId] = useState(null);

const dateChangeHandler = (value: DateRange | null, event: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
    setSelectedDateRange(value);
    
    const _timeoutId = window.setTimeout(() => dispatch(fetchFilteredData({ payload: { dateRange: value, selectedTools: selectedTools } })), 5000)
    setTimeoutId(_timeoutId);
}

const selectionChangeHandler = (value: string[]) => {
    if (value.length > 0) {
        if (timeoutId) {
            window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            setTimeoutId(null);
        }
        setSelectedTools(value);
        dispatch(fetchFilteredData({ payload: { dateRange: selectedDateRange, selectedTools: value } }))
    }
    ...
};
```